# Error creating site collection - Slow Query Duration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to create site collection but I see several errors in logs when doing this. I'm working on test environment...

> Creating site: URL "/" 94d3249e-2766-c0a9-cc0b-687468c08613
>
> Begin Query the AD to get the user email and display name. 94d3249e-2766-c0a9-cc0b-687468c08613
>
> Feature Activation: Activating Feature 'Fields' (ID: 'ca7bd552-10b1-4563-85b9-5ed1d39c962a') at URL http://sp2013:27000.
>
> A large block of literal text was sent to sql (length 93794).  This can result in blocking in sql and excessive memory use on the front end.
>
> Slow Query Duration: 2045.6606531853   94d3249e-2766-c0a9-cc0b-687468c08613
>       Line 6517: 10/20/2017 13:29:56.33   w3wp.exe (0x011C)                           0x1364  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        fa44    High        Slow Query StackTrace-Managed:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OnPostExecuteCommand(SqlCommand command, SqlQueryData monitoringData)
>   SqlCommand: 'EXEC @ReturnCode = proc_ProvisionContentType '22e947b3-6f22-4995-bf25-2c9f0dbab1d7','37eb0e92-d8e8-47e2-a33a-2c5f27541c90',N'',...

I haven't found information for 'Slow query duration' for this kind of scenarios, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like an issue with your SQL server fragmentation.

- I would recommend stopping the SharePoint services.
- Restart server
- Keep unused services off
- Try creating site collection

Then turn services one by one till you figure out the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal when creating a Site Collection. There is nothing to troubleshoot here.